# Prevent Protractor from finishing before promise has been resolved

Tags: protractor

I have some async WebDriverJS processing that is being skipped because the test is completing before they are are being resolve.  How do I get protractor to wait ?

e.g.: (both of these tests should fail ([potential ticket submitted](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/601))

```
  it('test promise ', function (done) {
      var d = protractor.promise.defer();
      d.fulfill(true)
      d.promise.then(function (item) {
          console.log("fulfill", item);
      });
      expect(d.promise)
          .toBe(false);
      console.log("test done");
  });

  it('test promise with timeout ', function (done) {
      var d = protractor.promise.defer();
      setTimeout(function () {
          console.log("fulfill");
          d.fulfill(true)
      }, 3000);

      d.promise.then(function (item) {
          console.log("fulfill", item);
      });
      expect(d.promise)
          .toBe(false);
      console.log("test done");
  });
```

Let me know if you need more information ... ?

This will return true.. if you remove the timeout and just set fulfill it will work...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Protractor side

The fix for this has been [merged 11 days ago](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/43ff9e5e2a0/jasminewd/spec/adapterSpec.js#L212)

You can have it working with `createFlow` but solution will be much simpler, just call `done()` after `fulfill` like this:

```
it('test promise with setTimeout ', function(done) {
  var d = protractor.promise.defer();
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("fulfill");
    d.fulfill('ok');
    done();
  }, 3000);
  expect(d).toBe('ok');
});
```

Currently on master branch so expect this to be shipped in [protractor >= 0.23.0](https://github.com/angular/protractor/releases)

#### Web app side (informative)

Protractor [doesn't know how to wait for setTimeout](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/35dcea01bf1d2a8e60f17e4310791ac5b5249b2c/spec/basic/synchronize_spec.js#L30)

But [does know how to wait for $timeout](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/35dcea01bf1d2a8e60f17e4310791ac5b5249b2c/spec/basic/synchronize_spec.js#L41)

Comment: Won't the test be ended before expect(d).toBe('ok') is run?

Comment: I've just run it, the test took 3 secs as expected and passed. expect(d) will hold until d is fulfilled.

Comment: Perhaps because the expect(d) is evaluated before done() is reached. That makes sense.

Comment: Also because Protractor patches Jasmine expect() so it always waits for promises to be resolved. See https://github.com/angular/jasminewd

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't get Nix's example to work and so I took Kato's suggestion and did the following:

```
describe('Tests stuff', function () {

    function do_work() {
        var d = protractor.promise.defer();
        protractor.promise.controlFlow().execute(function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                console.log("fulfill");
                d.fulfill(true)
            }, 3000);
        });
        return d;
    }

    it('test promise with timeout ', function () {
        protractor.promise.controlFlow().wait(do_work).then(function (done) {
            console.log("test done:" + done);
        });
    });
});
```

The out put is as expected and the method waits correctly, and then follows the next flow. My output:

```
Started
fulfill
test done:true
```

I'm sure there's many other ways to get this to work, however this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I need someone to validate this is the correct way to do it.. but I believe the issue was  the promise was not being added to the current control flow.

Solution:

```
it('test promise with timeout ', function (done) {
  var wait = protractor.promise.createFlow(function(flow){
      var d = protractor.promise.defer();
      flow.execute(function(){
          setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("fulfill");
            d.fulfill(true)
           }, 3000);
      });
  });

  expect(wait).toBe(false);
  console.log("test done");
 });
```

Comment: Looks like you can also use `protractor.promise.controlFlow().execute(methodThatReturnsPromise);` (no need for the `expect`, wait var, or sort of nested layout.