# What would be the return value when I use the statement _element = expect(locator.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I've been working on Protractor E2E tests. I would like to implement explicit waits in my tests instead of ptor.sleep and implicit waits.

So I would like to know if I can use any method which returns 'boolean' type when I searched for an element..?

Comment: Your question isnt very clear....

Comment: expect doesn't have a return value, if it's what you are asking for...  not sure if i got your question ...

Answer (score 0):

Well it sounds like you're waiting for the promise to resolve.  I'd take a peek at this [Prevent Protractor from finishing before promise has been resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22330831/prevent-protractor-from-finishing-before-promise-has-been-resolved)

$timeout