# Prevent protractor from exiting before jasmine reporter completes

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I've created a jasmine reporter that performs an slow async task, but protractor is exiting before the reporter's work is completed.  How to make protractor wait for the slow reporter to complete?

In my reporter, the slow task is simulated by the `setTimeout` :

```
// SlowReporter.js
SlowReporter.prototype.reportRunnerResults = function() {
    var p = q.defer();
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("Slow reporting op finished");
        p.resolve();
    }, 10000);
    return p.promise;
};
```

But, when I wire it in,

```
// protractor.conf.js
onPrepare: function() {
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SlowReporter());
}
```

..protractor exits before the slow task completes.  Protractor doesn't seem to respect the promise returned by the reporter.

Please note I'm not asking [how to make protractor wait on an async test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22330831/prevent-protractor-from-finishing-before-promise-has-been-resolved), rather how to make protractor wait on a jasmine reporter after the tests complete.

Comment: Does it give a spec timeout error? If yes, then you can use jasmineNodeOpts: {defaultTimeoutInterval: 20000} in config.js

Answer (score 0):

FFR solved by defining a `.completed()` method in `SlowReporter` which returns a promise that is resolved when the reporter completes;  then have `protractor.spec.js` return this promise in the `onCleanUp()`.  Only works with protractor >= 1.1.0 .

Open to better answers/approaches.

Comment: If you still have the code, can you share this solution? I'd like to try it.

Comment: @Corey sorry I don't.