# browser.get() Does Not Work

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, promise, protractor

When I print out the url in console, I get the appropriate url. However, when I later try to get that url with browser.get(), I get the following error:

> Failed: Parameter 'url' must be a string, not objectFailed: Parameter 'url' must be a string, not object

I don't really understand why this is happening. To me it seems that:
a). It's a string, since I can print it.
b). ...I was going to say "the promise is resolved"...but I am actually not so sure here. Do all beforeAll promises get resolved before starting the it statements? How do I fix this?

```
beforeAll(function(){
    //some stuff 
    browser.waitForAngular();
    createdItemUrl = browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url){
        console.log('URL:' + url);
    });
});

it('Keeps failing lololol', function(){
    browser.get(createdItemUrl);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is still the [control flow](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md) in action. `getCurrentUrl()` is a promise that has to be resolved if you want to reuse the actual URL value:

```
var createdItemUrl;

beforeAll(function(){
    //some stuff 
    browser.waitForAngular();

    createdItemUrl = browser.getCurrentUrl();
});

it('Keeps failing lololol', function() {
    // createdItemUrl is a promise
    createdItemUrl.then(function (url) {
        browser.get(url);
    });
});
```

Or, you may also add a blocking `defer()` -> `fulfill()` mechanism to make it wait/block until the promise is resolved, see:

- [Prevent Protractor from finishing before promise has been resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22330831/prevent-protractor-from-finishing-before-promise-has-been-resolved)

Answer (score 1):

`createdItemUrl`, as written, is an object. And inside the `then`, `url` *is* a string. Try it this way:

```
var createdItemUrl;

beforeAll(function(){
    //some stuff 
    browser.waitForAngular();
    browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
        createdItemUrl = url;
    });
});

it('Keeps failing lololol', function(){
    browser.get(createdItemUrl);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Brine, accepted Alec's answer because of the explanations, but yours was helpful as well.