# protractor - how to get the result of an array of promises into another array and use that array in some other function

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, protractor

I got an array of promises from the below code but I am finding really difficult to get the data into another array so that I can use the array in some other function.

```
    var AdidToCheckInDelete = [];

    var getArray = function() {

    var result = element.all(by.repeater('adId in campaign.adIds')).map(function (elem) {
                return elem.all(by.model('campaign.adIds[$index]')).getAttribute('value').then(function (text) {
                    return text ? text[0] : text;
                    });
                });

    result.then(function (elem) {
                console.log('element is' + elem);
                var array = elem;
                AdidToCheckInDelete.push(array);
                    console.log('array created with values + AdidToCheckInDelete);
                });
            console.log('Array outside the scope is' +AdidToCheckInDelete);
 //PROBLEM AdidToCheckInDelete is Empty
            };
```

Pushing the value of array and printing them within the scope is giving the array but printing it outside the scope is giving an empty array.
Please provide me the solution for this. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason for your array being empty is because Protractor is executing your **console.log()** statement even before the promise of **map()** function is resolved to which your **push()** method is chained. To resolve this try console logging your array after the promise is resolved, in your case its already done after push method the **array** variable.

```
result.then(function (elem) {
    console.log('element is' + elem);
    var array = elem;
    AdidToCheckInDelete.push(array);
    //Printing array here makes sense as map() function promise is resolved and then you are trying to print it
    console.log('array created with values + AdidToCheckInDelete);
});
```

Or you can chain your console logging next to function containing push method. Here's how you can do it -

```
result.then(function (elem) {
    console.log('element is' + elem);
    var array = elem;
    AdidToCheckInDelete.push(array);
})
.then(function(){
    console.log('Array outside the scope is' +AdidToCheckInDelete);
    //Your array wont be empty now
    //If you want to use your array for next operation you can do it here
});
```

You can also try adding a blocking defer() -> fulfill() mechanism to make it wait/block until the promise is resolved, see:

[- Prevent Protractor from finishing before promise has been resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22330831/prevent-protractor-from-finishing-before-promise-has-been-resolved)

Comment: The last sentence looks familiar :)

Comment: Yes, your answer for another post helped me in learning about the defer() -> fulfill() method. So thought it will be better if i post it that way. All credit should go to you @alecxe :)