# Protractor specs leaking

Tags: protractor, angular-promise

I'm still quite new to promises and the like and I need some help with this problem. One of my it blocks does not end before the next one begins ending up in a StaleElementReferenceError a whole specfile later from where the code was supposed to be called.

listView.js (I know it looks weird but I set it up this way for an unrelated reason):

```
module.exports = function () {
    var public = {};

public.checkFilters = function (filters) {
        var promises = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < filters.length; i++) {
            promises[i] = getFilterPromise(filters[i]);
        }
        return protractor.promise.all(promises);
    };

    var getFilterPromise = function (filter) {
        return public.getHeaderIndex(filter.on).then(function (headerIndex) {
            return checkRows(filter.values, headerIndex);
        });
    };

    public.getHeaderIndex = function (text) {
        var headers = table.all(by.tagName('th'));
        var correctHeaderIndex;
        return headers.each(function (header, index) {
            header.getText().then(function (actualHeaderText) {
                if (actualHeaderText === text) {
                    correctHeaderIndex = index;
                }
            })
        }).then(function () {
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                if (correctHeaderIndex) {
                    resolve(correctHeaderIndex);
                } else {
                    reject('Header not found');
                }
            });
        });
    };

    public.getWorkflowCount = function () {
        return workflows.count();
    };

    var checkRows = function (matchers, headerIndex) {
        var mismatch = false;
        return workflows.each(function (element, index) {
            public.getTextFromCell(index, headerIndex).then(function (actual) {
                if (!anyMatch(actual, matchers)) {
                    mismatch = true;
                }
            });
        }).then(function () {
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                if (mismatch) {
                    reject('Header not found');
                } else {
                    resolve('all rows matched');
                }
            });
        });
    };

    var anyMatch = function (actual, matchers) {
        var match = false;
        for (var j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
            if (text === values[j]) {
                match = true;
            }
        }
        return match;
    };

    public.getTextFromCell = function (row, column) {
        return workflows.get(row).all(by.tagName('td')).get(column).getText();
    };


    return public;
}();
```

LV_00:

```
describe('LV_00:', function () {

    it('statusfilter', function () { 
        P.listView.filter('status', H.regStatus.S.inProgress);
    });
    it('statusfilter works', function () {
        P.listView.checkFilters([{
            on: H.lang.S.status,
            values: [H.regStatus.S.inProgress]
        }]);
    });

});
```

Comment: What is `P.listView.filter`? Thanks.

Comment: Oh sorry, P.listview is the pageobject I made for that view containing the listview.js file. The filter method is what actually activates a filter on the page but I left those methods out of the post because they are quite unrelated and it's already a lot of code to post :P

Comment: Okay, but `filter()` might be the problem in this case. Is there any reason you've put `filter()` call into the `it()` as opposed to, say, `beforeEach()`?

Comment: Yes I don't want to apply the same filter every time so every time I want to test a filter I use a new it and activate a new filter, after which I can test if the filter works.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should move the test preparation code into the `beforeEach()`:

```
describe('LV_00:', function () {
    beforeEach('statusfilter', function () { 
        P.listView.filter('status', H.regStatus.S.inProgress);
    });

    it('statusfilter works', function () {
        P.listView.checkFilters([{
            on: H.lang.S.status,
            values: [H.regStatus.S.inProgress]
        }]);
    });
});
```

You may also need to use the [`done` callback function](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/stips/using-jasmine-2.0s-new-done-function-to-test-asynchronous-processes.html):

```
describe('LV_00:', function (done) {
    beforeEach('statusfilter', function () { 
        P.listView.filter('status', H.regStatus.S.inProgress).then(function () {
            done();
        });
    });

    it('statusfilter works', function () {
        P.listView.checkFilters([{
            on: H.lang.S.status,
            values: [H.regStatus.S.inProgress]
        }]);
    });
});
```

assuming `filter()` returns a promise.

Comment: I won't use a beforeEach but I will look into using the done function, although it looks kinda messy :/

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution thanks to alecxe proposing to use done() I used the following after some googling around.

```
it('statusfilter', function () {
        P.listView.filter('status', H.regStatus.S.inProgress);
    });
    it('statusfilter works', function () {
        protractor.promise.controlFlow().execute(function () {
            return P.listView.checkFilters([{
                on: H.lang.S.status,
                values: [H.regStatus.S.inProgress]
            }]);
        });
    });
```

Found here: [Prevent Protractor from finishing before promise has been resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22330831/prevent-protractor-from-finishing-before-promise-has-been-resolved)